# Windows Runtime Component and Dependency Injection. Can they work together?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, windows-runtime, portable-class-library

In the past I have worked with PCLs and DI in a manner like this.

- In the PCL I declare some interfaces.
- I use these interfaces as dependecies(in the constructor) on classes that the PCL exposes.
- The project that references the PCL then creates implementations for these interfaces, injects them to the classes from the PCL and uses them.

I use this architecture because it makes for easily testable PCLs which usually include most of the business logic of the application.

I have recently tried to "port" a PCL to a Windows Runtime Component and found that I cannot expose any of the classes with their constructors dependent on the interfaces, as the interfaces are not valid Windows Runtime parameter types.

I understand that this is a limitation of the Windows Runtime Component so my question is: Can I inject a dependency(that is a custom type) to a Windows Runtime Component from the project referencing it?